# Data for Japanese options

Tags: options, historical-data, option-data

I'm working on an academic project that requires data for options tracking ~300 large Japanese stocks between 2010$-$2020.

The standard data source I've seen quoted in academic papers is OptionMetrics, but my academic institution only has a subscription to US markets.

**What are some data sources that give Japanese/international options data that an academic institution would likely have access to?**

My best bet right now is either Bloomberg or Datastream. Bloomberg is rather tough, since it makes it difficult to export large amounts of data. Datastream seems decent in that it doesn't have any download caps, but I was wondering if there are any other alternatives out there.